# How to prevent a process using UDP datagrams from receiving its own messages?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing a sender-receiver protocol with ACKs in C. Whenever the **sender** sends a packet, the **receiver** will send a correspondant ACK and then wait for the next packet. The problem is that since I'm testing everything on the same machine (using `127.0.0.1` as address) the receiver will receive its own ACKs in an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code from the receiver side (all inside a `while` loop):

```
if ((recvfrom(sockfd, buff, PACKETSZ + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sndaddr, &len)) < 0) {
    perror("recvfrom");
    return -1;
}
fprintf(stderr, "Packet received: '%s'.\n", buff);
// Get sequence number (seqn) from the packet        
char answer[PACKETSZ];
snprintf(answer, PACKETSZ, "%d-ACK", seqn);
printf("Sending '%s'\n", answer);
if (sendto(sockfd, answer, strlen(answer) + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sndaddr, sizeof(sndaddr)) < 0) {
    perror("sendto");
    return -1;
}
```

How can I **prevent a process from receiving the datagrams being sent by itself**?

Comment: Are you using the same port for client and server, perhaps?

Comment: @C.Gonzalez yes... how am I supposed to use different ones?

Comment: Normally you determine a port for the server (in your code) so clients know here to connect. For the client you let the OS give you a port (i. e. just use sendto() or whatever it´s called in C, with the IP and port number of the server).

Comment: The point here is that I can't assume which is client and which server. I only have a sender and a receiver... and they both call `sendto` and  `recvfrom`, just in different order. (Sender `sendto`-`recvfrom` and receiver `recvfrm`-`sendto`)

Comment: @Robb1 OK, you have designed yourself into a corner.  Use VM's for testing?

Comment: the UDP protocol is a 'one way' protocol.  So the code needs to generate a second socket, the port number needs to be different,  You need to decide which is the client and which is the server.  Then write the code accordingly.   There are LOTS of client/server examples on stackoverflow (and elsewhere)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can keep the socket from receiving the message in this situation, rather you need to use the address parameter to recvfrom and ignore the message if it came from your own socket.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! "ignore the message if it came from your own socket" how to do that?

Comment: @Robb1 umm what?   Just compare and ignore if match!